# How to encrypt 1 float with 4 floats

Tags: security, encryption, hash, cryptography, sha

This is kind of a hard problem to describe, and I am naive about cryptography. So please excuse me as I stumble through trying to explain this.

I have a one 32-bit float value, this is the "source" float.
Then I have four 32-bit float values, these are the "key" floats.

I want to somehow encode or obfuscate the one "source" float with the four "key" floats. The resulting "encoded source" float would then be stored as 4 "encoded" floats. So then if you have these four "encoded" floats, the four "key" floats and the "encodedSource" float, you can then get the original "source" float.

Here is a crude example of this:

```
// Crude encoding
float encoded0 = Random.Range(-1, 1);
float encoded1 = Random.Range(-1, 1);
float encoded2 = Random.Range(-1, 1);
float encoded3 = Random.Range(-1, 1);

float encodedSource = source;
encodedSource += encoded0 * _key0;
encodedSource += encoded1 * _key1;
encodedSource += encoded2 * _key2;
encodedSource += encoded3 * _key3
```

With this you would end up with `encodedSource` float, `encoded0-3` floats and `_key0-3` floats. Then with just these values you could decode this to get the original `source` float.

```
// Crude decoding
float source = encodedSource;
source -= encoded0 * _key0;
source -= encoded1 * _key1;
source -= encoded2 * _key2;
source -= encoded3 * _key3
```

So the problem with this algorithm is, if you have only the `encodedSource` float and the `encoded0-3` floats it would be extremely easy to reverse engineer this to get the `key` floats.

Is there some kind of algorithm which would make it more difficult to discern the key floats.

Comment: Why do they have to be floats? Why can't they just be treated as 32-bit quantities? The problem is that no floating point binary operation is guaranteed to be reversible. There are always approximate results, overflow, underflow, etc. scenarios that would ruin the reversibility needed to decrypt. If `a` and `b` have mantissas with a total of 24+24=48 bits of entropy, then `c`=`a * b` discards 24 bits of that entropy and thus we cannot guarantee that `c/a == b`.

Answer (score 2):

With cryptography it is always a bad idea to design your own, unless you are an expert.  So it is best to make use of already existing cryptosystems.

You want to use four 32-bit floats as your key.  4 x 32 = 128 bits, and AES expects a 128 bit (16 byte) key.  So, use AES for your encryption.

You want to encrypt a 32-bit float, that is 4 bytes, or perhaps 8 hex digits, of plaintext.  That is short for a plaintext, so I would suggest using AES in [counter mode (CTR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR)) so you do not have to get into things like padding.  You will need a unique nonce (**n**umber used **once**) with each key for full security.

Comment: The unique nonce (IV) for AES-CTR is 128-bit large. So, when used matches the storage requirement of the question (4 encoded floats and 1 encoded source float): 160-bit for IV+ciphertext.

Comment: Might be best to use the so-called *key* floats as inputs to a KDF to generate the AES key and IV. If the key floats have low enough entropy it should probably be a password-based KDF. It might also be wise to divvy up the 128 bits of "extra" output into other values, e.g. an authentication tag, or an authentication tag and salt. It all very much depends on the details which unfortunately are not provided in the question.

Comment: To be honest I really don't have enough prerequisite knowledge to really follow this well. Is there some coursera course, or youtube series that would be a good crash course in this stuff?